# How to get data attributes of the clicked element on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, I'd like to know if there is a way to get the data attributes of the element being clicked on during a focusout event.

My page produces search results in a small div on the side when the user types into the search input. 
The problem is that when the focus is lost from the input, I want the search results to disappear.
I wrote the following code to accomplish this.

```
$('#chat-search').focusout(function(){
    $('#chat-search').val(""); //Search input is cleared
    $('.search-results').hide(); //The search results div is hidden
    $('.people').show(); // Shows the previous div that was taken up by the search results
});
```

The problem is, I need to get information from the clicked div contained within the search-results class. The div that contains the data has the search-person class and there are many of them within the search-results div.

```
$('body').on('click', '.search-person', function(){
    var userId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(userId);
    $('#chat-search').addClass('center-text');
    $('#chat-search').val("");
    $('.search-results').hide();
    $('.people').show();
});
```

The search-person click function does not fire because the focusout event has hidden the element that was clicked. Focusout always appears to trigger before the on click event.

I tried to fire a normal on click event so that when the user clicks on anything that is not the search results or the input, the same code is executed as in the method above. This workaround is not perfect though, as it does not trigger if the search input loses focus because the user pressed tab.

```
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).is($('#chat-search'))){ // If the search input is selected
        $('#chat-search').removeClass('center-text');
        $('.search-results').val("");
        $('.people').hide();
        $('search-results').show();
    }
    else if (!($(e.target).is($('.search-person')))){ 
        // If the selected element is neither the search input nor the search result
        $('#chat-search').addClass('center-text');
        $('#chat-search').val("");
        $('.search-results').hide();
        $('.people').show();
    }
});
```

Is there any way to find out the data attributes of the clicked element on focusout when the elements are going to be hidden when the input loses focus?

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="search-container">
    <input id="chat-search" class="chat-search center-text" placeholder="Search Users">
</div>
<div class="user-container scrollbar">
    <ul class="people">
    </ul>
    <ul class="search-results">
    </ul>
</div>
```

And within the search results ul, results with this HTML are generated through an ajax request.

```
<li class="search-person" data-id="someId">
    <div class="search-left">
        <img class="search-image" src="someurl">
    </div>
    <div class="search-right">
        <div class="search-name">
            Text here
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you also share the HTML which you are trying, please?

Comment: I've added the relevant html also

Comment: so why not use `$('.search-results').attr("data-id");` ? I mean its a bit unclear to what exactly you are trying to achive

Comment: The attribute belongs to the li elements with the search-person class.
There are many search-person elements so I can't just get the attribute directly like that. I have to know which element was clicked on.

Comment: try adding global variable like window.previousClicked = 'button1Id'; (this will be set when the button is clicked, then use that variable when focusout

Comment: but how can you hide the element on focusout and click them at the same time?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph That's the problem. I want to hide on focusout but also acknowledge which element was clicked at the same time.

Comment: @cjatstackoverflow The click happens at the same time as the focusout event. When would I be able to set the value of the global variable?

Comment: lets keep the solution aside, if you hide, how do you think someone can even click the element?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph The search results are not hidden until the focus is lost on the input. Until you click away from the input, the results are still visible and can be clicked on. The ajax request is trigged on keyup so there's no problem getting the results without losing focus.

Comment: @Marissa Try changing the focusout to $('#elem').on('input', function(){}), or try checking if the previous value of the input is the same after focusing out, that way you don have to search again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by setting a timeout for the focusout event, so that the click event could fire before the search results disappeared.
If anyone has this issue in the future, here is how I solved it.

```
$('#chat-search').focusout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("focus out!");
        $('#chat-search').addClass('center-text');
        $('#chat-search').val("");
        $('.search-results').hide();
        $('.people').show();
    }, 300)
});
```

Comment: Using timeouts is not the cleanest way to set dependencies. But it works, so I used in project too. In an almost identical task.